# Sending arguments to ComposeView?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

One astonishing thing about my research into compose interop was that there is absolutely no coverage anywhere on the subject of Activity/Fragment to compose communication .

Isn't this a very commonly occurring situation in which a fragment/activity might want to refresh its content ? .

This is how I use my compose in fragment (standard way)

```
    class Fragment
    {
      onCreateView() {
    
    showCompose()
    }
    
    private fun showCompose() {
        binding.composeView.apply {
          setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
          setContent {
            MotivoTheme() {
              Text(text="this is compose")
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

The only way i see at the moment to send arguments to compose view is via a state variable in the Fragment , something like this

```
class Fragment {
  var somethingHappened = false

  private fun showCompose() {
    binding.composeView.apply {
      setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
      setContent {
        MotivoTheme() {
          if (somethingHappened) {
            Text(text = "Something happenede")
          } else {
            Text(text = "this is compose")
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This approach obviously is sinful .
Any guesses how to do  this elegantly ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is my understanding that the whole Fragment UI idea is basically deprecated. Composables aren't supposed to run inside Fragments -- they're meant to replace them. [Here's](https://sonique6784.medium.com/jetpack-compose-and-the-fall-of-fragments-54bf9977da1a) a very basic write-up about it, but I'm sure that you can find others.

You can technically have Compose interact with the old View architecture using the [Interoperability API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis), but your life will be much simpler if you just embrace Compose.